# Populate date field when another field is changed

Tags: workflow, formula-field, field-update, field-dependencies

I have two fields: Turnover and Turnover Date. The 'Turnover Date' is a formula field which needs to be automatically populated when the 'Turnover' field is changed/updated. Is there anyway to achieve with formula, or should I go for workflow rule?

Comment: Is it a formula in SFDC or by formula you means it is a field that is calculated and does not require user input.

Comment: it is a read-only formula field and does not require user input

Comment: Then, It depends on how is the calculation done. What is the logic for the calculation?

Comment: there is no calculation logic. I want to capture the date whenever the turnover field is updated/changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your question to mean that Turnover Date should reflect the last date/time that Turnover was changed. This cannot be done on a formula on its own.

A workflow rule, process builder or flow can do the trick (if Turnover is changed, update Turnover Date to current time), or  you can enable history tracking for the Turnover field.